# Saving image data without loading it

Tags: matlab, function

In Matlab there is a function called `matfile`. With it you can "Access and change variables directly in MAT-files, without loading into memory".

Now I wonder whether it is possible with other things too.

For example: I do have a folder with images with the format 'png'. Now I want to change that folder for some of these images.

```
save(Image1.png, oldfilename, newfilename)
```

It is possible if I load the image then save it again. But for a lot of images it would require a high computational effort. A loop would be needed too.

So is there already an implemented function somewhere or does somebody have a brilliant idea to solve this like a pro? ;)

Greetings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `movefile` command to rename the files.

```
movefile('oldfilename','Newfilename')
```

Comment: Does it move a copy or the actual file?

Comment: It moves it. See [movefile](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/movefile.html)

Comment: Ok it moves the actual file. But thanks to you I know now where to look. It is the help chapter "working with files and folders" I think I will find something usefull or maybe I just use movefile in the end.

Comment: @TanjaLange Otherwise you would want to use [`copyfile`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/copyfile.html)